# Routing Error! "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH]"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

When a user clicks submit with this _form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@routine, url: create_freebie_routine_path(params[:id])) do |f| %>

  <%= f.date_select %>

<% end %>
```

He gets this error: `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/routines/2/create_freebie")`

I can't figure out how to fix it. The idea is that a user will submit the above _form with entered `freebie_date` and then the controller will add +1 `freebie` via the `create_freebie` action to the updated `@routine`

**routes**

```
  resources :routines do
    member do
      get :new_freebie
      post :create_freebie
    end
  end
```

**routines_controller**

```
  def new_freebie
    @routine = current_user.routines.find(params[:id])
    @routine.freebie_date = Date.yesterday
    respond_modal_with @routine
  end

  def create_freebie
    @routine = current_user.routines.find(params[:id])
    @routine.freebie = @routine.freebie + 1
    @routine.save
    respond_modal_with @routine, location: root_path
    flash[:alert] = 'Freebie added'
  end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to replace this

```
  resources :routines do
    member do
      get :new_freebie
      post :create_freebie
    end
  end
```

with:

```
  resources :routines do
    member do
      get :new_freebie
      patch :create_freebie
    end
  end
```

Notice the change from `post` to `patch`

---

Another solution is to specify the `method` to `post` in the form without changing your `routes`:

```
<%= simple_form_for @routine, url: create_freebie_routine_path(params[:id]), method: :post do |f| %>

  <%= f.date_select %>

<% end %>
```